# Ionic 3 - Angular when import TestBed get Error : afterAll\nUncaught

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, testing, ionic-framework

I'm working on an Ionic 3 App and I have a problem when I want to use **TestBed** class. I use these commands to create the project.

```
ionic start myApp tabs
npm install karma-cli -g
npm install karma --save-dev
npm install jasmine --save-dev
npm install karma-jasmine --save-dev
npm install @types/jasmine --save-dev
npm install jasmine-core --save-dev
npm install ts-node --save-dev
npm install angular-cli --save-dev
```

I use karma to create this *karma.conf.js* :

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    files: [
      'src/**/*Spec.js'
    ],

    exclude: [
    ],

    preprocessors: {
    },

    reporters: ['progress'],

    port: 9876,

    colors: true,

    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    autoWatch: true,

    browsers: ['Chrome'],

    singleRun: false,

    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

I create the *src/app/pages/home/homeSpec.js* file with this content :

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core';

describe("some tests", () => {

  it("True", function () {
    expect(true).toEqual(true);
  });

});
```

I get the following output when I use **karma start** :

```
------------------- without TestBed import ----------------
27 02 2018 23:45:55.793:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
27 02 2018 23:45:55.807:INFO [karma]: Karma v2.0.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
27 02 2018 23:45:55.808:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
27 02 2018 23:45:55.812:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
27 02 2018 23:45:57.600:INFO [Chrome 64.0.3282 (Mac OS X 10.13.3)]: Connected on socket ysC5F7d28isYt8oAAAAA with id 47800734
Chrome 64.0.3282 (Mac OS X 10.13.3): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.002 secs / 0 secs)

------------------- with TestBed import ----------------
27 02 2018 23:46:04.564:INFO [watcher]: Changed file "/Volumes/JedemaKey/ionic_book/Chapitres/ionic/testtest/myApp/src/pages/home/homeSpec.js".
Chrome 64.0.3282 (Mac OS X 10.13.3) ERROR
  {
    "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {",
    "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"
  }
Chrome 64.0.3282 (Mac OS X 10.13.3): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.018 secs / 0 secs)
```

Why I get this error ?
How can I import TestBed class ?

### Edit

I get same error il I can to import another class like in the following code :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
// This line works in .ts module in same directory.

describe("Test de la page informations", () => {

  it("True", function () {
    expect(true).toEqual(true);
  });

});
```

I get the same error if I give .ts extension to file...

Do you have a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly, I found solution in this Github page (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-unit-testing-example/issues/79). I downgrade jasmine version to 2.99.0 by using this command :

```
npm install --save-dev jasmine@^2.99.0
```